# In Exacttarget Salesforce Reports and Objects options not appearing in Import activity dropdown

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have integrated the BU I am working on with my user in salescloud(SFDC). I can also view and send emails from the marketing cloud tab from salescloud(login.salesforce.com) through the same exacttarget BU. I can also see the salesforce reports and objects in Admin > File locations, but in the import activity (automation >> activities) I can only see the enhanced STP location option and not able to find the salesforce reports and objects option through which I can import salesforce report data into a salesforce DE within marketing cloud. Please help, need it urgently !!
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We do not have it either in Automation Studio. Currently the only option appears to be using the Interactions > Import activity in Email Studio.

Then use the previously created Import Activity in Automation Studio to populate a Data Extension as needed.

Comment: And if you don't have interactions enabled within Email Studio anymore you can have support re-enable them for this use case.

Answer (score 0):

You need to integrate marketing cloud user (the user which you are using to perform import function) with salesforce system user, in order to access/view the option "Salesforce objects and report" in "Import" functionality.